VSCodeVim Custom Commands Not Executing Properly in .vscodevimrc
I'm trying to modify my $HOME/.vscodevimrc to add some commands to call vscode specific functionality like workbench.action.closeSidebar and workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal but these just echo the command at the bottom of vscode when I call them using my chosen shortcuts. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
"map vim:leader to <Space> in settings first"
let mapleader = " "

nnoremap <leader>to :tabnew<CR>
nnoremap <leader>tx :tabclose<CR>
nnoremap <leader>tn :tabnext<CR>
nnoremap <leader>tp :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap <leader>ie :e<Space>
nnoremap <leader>il :e!<CR>

nnoremap <leader>cs :call VSCodeCall('workbench.action.closeSidebar')<CR>
nnoremap <leader>xe :call VSCodeCall('workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal')<CR>

